# How to upload an image to google storage from anuglar app?

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, image-upload

I want to implement an image upload to google storage, below is my requirement

1. Through our web application (angularjs) user is able to upload user profile image
2. Image is saved on google storage
3. In our web application user profile image can be viewed in different sizes like 30 X 30 pixels, 150 X 150 pixels, , 250 X 250 pixels

I know an easy way to upload source image to s3(directly from angular app) and then execute transcoder to convert image in different required sizes. I also heard that google app engine has api to resize image on the fly, If yes then:

1. How it does costing per request?
2. Does it cache if the request for same image for same size is already requested
3. How this solution scalable if there are hundreds of requests per second?
4. Does it supports other features like convert an image to B/W, crop etc
5. Sample angular javascript code to upload an image to google storage

Reference: https://medium.com/google-cloud/uploading-resizing-and-serving-images-with-google-cloud-platform-ca9631a2c556#.16xdg78t1

Comment: Have you done any research on this yourself?

Comment: which language is running the backend or which application or module type is the angular hosted on. e.g java, node or python etc

Comment: @TheophilusOmoregbee, its nodejs